# WPF Label how to update width for proper animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to achieve a simple label scroller(found the idea here: [Scroller StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093614/scroller-like-animation-on-a-label-in-wpf). I have a label, which I want to animate with help of DoubleAnimation class like this:

**In constructor I implement event for Loaded:**

```
    public Web()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetDefaultBrowser();
        SetDefaultWebsite();
        //TextBlockSong.Text = GetSongName(GetBrowserName(), GetWebsiteName());
        Loaded += Window1_Loaded;

    }
```

**Event:**

```
    void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));
        LabelNameSong.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
    }
```

Everything works until I update my **LabelNameSong** content. The **LabelNameSong** width stays the same as before, and my animation doesn't work properly from the start anymore(with updated text).

I update my **LabelNameSong** with ListBox_SelectionChanged event:

```
            private void ListBoxWebsite_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double k = LabelNameSong.Width;
        double z = LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
        LabelWebsiteName.Content = "Now on " + GetWebsiteName();
        LabelNameSong.Content = GetSongName(GetBrowserName(), GetWebsiteName());

        k = LabelNameSong.Width;
        z = LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
    }
```

I used those to measure width, and found out that it doesn't update the width of **LabelNameSong**. I am new here, don't even know if it should.

This is my xaml:

```
        <Canvas Background="White" Margin="0,182,58,0" >
        <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" Height="80" Width="346"  >
            <Label FontSize="25" Foreground="#666666" Name="LabelNameSong" Canvas.Top="27" Height="30" Width="Auto" Content="This is very long text, I am testing it!" FontFamily="Calibri Light"/>
        </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
```

So my question is, what could I do to update the width of my **LabelNameSong**, and how should I re-call **Window1_Loaded** event so new instance of DoubleAnimation would work with updated ActualWidth?

```
        doubleAnimation.From = -LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap the Animation logic into a method and call from Loaded event and any other event you need

```
private void CreateAnimation()
{
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));
    LabelNameSong.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
}

void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateAnimation();
}

private void LabelNameSong_SizeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateAnimation();
}
```

But you can probably do it all in Xaml using Triggers and get rid of all that code behind.

In the example below the animation will start on Load and restart when the Size changes

Example:

```
 <Label x:Name="LabelNameSong" Content="Hello" >
    <Label.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="scroll">
            <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LabelNameSong}" Duration="00:00:10"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Right)"
              Storyboard.TargetName="LabelNameSong"
              RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Label.Resources>

    <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource scroll}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource scroll}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Comment: You are the savior of lives good sir. Thank you! Btw as you can see in my code my first position of text is -ActualWidth and goes all along Canvas's size, and repeats. Which means it goes like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFAnimation1/marq1.gif - RightToLeft example. I like your XAML approach, but can you give me a hint how can I use DoubleAnimation From as negative position? Thanks

Comment: If yu check my answer in the link below there is a converter that does exactly that, the Scrolling in that answer is a bit different but the converter is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation